# OpenURL works in editor and runtime but does not work after building onto Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, href

So I am trying to make a button that opens up to a webpage when clicked. Here is the code for the function:

```
public void ToHyperLink()
    {
        string theURL = parentButton.GetComponent<BLButton>().btnRefObj.GetComponent<HyperlinkAttri>().prodURL;
        Application.OpenURL(theURL);
    }
```

The URL is passed through the inspector like this:
[image]

This works perfectly fine when testing it on my PC, but once it is built to my Android phone it stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it. `Application.OpenURL("http://google.com");` works fine.Give the link directly and check if it is coming.You can install Android Logcat from package manager and connect android phone via usb and click build and run and check for any errors.

Comment: hey, thanks for the response, i tried without "www" as suggested and it works! but what if I wanted to visit a page with some path behind eg if i wanted to go to x.com and it has y subpage, if i used "http://x.com/y" this would just bring me to x.com home page, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Again I tested with the above code with the other links.It was exactly loading the links which I gave. I gave link "https://Link/pages/about" and worked perfectly fine.Also using "www" is not an issue I guess . I used www in the above link and it opened the sub page.